# Where is Billy?

Tags: story

You went on a walk with Billy but he got lost. Since you're his babysitter, you have to find him! He mentioned six different local places that he would have wanted to travel to: The park, the modern game store, the cave, the dairy farm, the pet store, and the valley.

You think he said something about two game stores, but you aren't sure.

He likes games and has a Nintendo Gamecube, a console from about 18 years ago.

You got a text message from the pet store about a missing child.

He mentioned wanting to go to the farm the most.

He's allergic to cows and cats.

You saw him walk off to the direction of the cave, which was in the vicinity of the farm, but to the left of a forest.

He's not an active child but has active friends.

It was noon when he got lost.

You get a text from the farmer confirming that he had been at the farm, and had gone off in the direction of the park, but there's a forest in the way; maybe there's an opening.

It's been three hours since he was lost.

The game store closes at 2:30.

The park is currently having a massive tree cut down.

The valley is in between the cave and the forest; the only way to get around it is to go to the left.

There are lethal lions in the valley.

With these clues, can you figure out where Billy is? Are you going to have to explain to his parents about how you lost him?

Comment: Are we to assume he only visited each place once?

Comment: @Nautilus Who says he visited each place?

Comment: Good god, Gamecube is an adult now? Jeez, I'm getting old...

Comment: *(this was mis-tagged -- "logical deduction" refers to applying formal rules of logic, not merely reasoning through clues to find an answer. It **appears** there is insufficient information here to definitively answer the question, so it is likely to be **too broad**. In a comment you suggest analyzing the text for "clip hints", whatever that means; if there are other details concealed in the text or in how the puzzle is composed, you may need to add additional tags to point this out.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Billy is

> at the pet store.
> Most of the clues are misdirection or irrelevant. Billy is allergic to cows, but that didn't stop him from going to the farm, as evidenced by a text you got from the farmer. The only actionable clue is that you received a text about a missing child at the pet store. Presumably if you lost Billy and are looking for him and get a text about a missing child at the pet store, you would immediately head to the pet store and probably also call them and ask them to keep the child there.
> The text from the farm states that he was there, but is there no longer, and all the clues about seeing him heading in a certain direction are all in past tense and he could have gone anywhere after that. Only the pet store clue doesn't specifically say that he isn't there anymore and seems like it could be in present tense. That's where he is, the pet store.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

Billy might be in the

> park.

The farmer told you that

> Billy left the farm and headed to the park, since he might had an allergic reaction when he got near the cows.

The game store

> closes at 2:30, it was 12:00 (noon) when he got lost, the time now is 3:00, so he mustn't be in the game store.

He isn't

> in the pet shop, since he is allergic to cats, and will have an allergic reaction when he gets near cats.

He wouldn't be in

> the valley either, since he once mentioned he wanted to go there, and as a babysitter, you probably told him that there are lions.

Although

> you saw him walking towards the cave, he wouldn't be there since he will meet the valley when he goes through the forest, in which there are lethal lions.

He has

> 'active friends', who might have gone hanging out with him in the park, where children mostly go.

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Thanks @OmegaKrypton for helping me edit the answer!

Comment: @ΩKr Wow you are so active

Answer (score 1):

Spoiler:

> Billy dies in the end

Moving on to the answer to the riddle, I am not familiar with the versions but .... believe that Billy is having **a wonderful life**.

Hence, Billy is at ....

> anywhere. I don't really know, but he will be back at his place by the end of the day.

Because .....

> all the places referenced here are places in the game of **Harvest Moon** or **Story of Season**, depending on which generation do you come from.
>   
>  I am thinking that it is **"A Wonderful Life"** (the first version that came out on GameCube) which is referenced here. Couldn't find a map to verify, and all based on my faint memory of the game.
>  
>  the dead giveaways are references to 
> the farm and that the Game store closes at 2:30PM (a common concept of time-based events throughout the game series)

& No, you don't have to explain to Billy's parents.
I always wondered why Billy's parents never questioned about him lol.

Comment: The question only has a logic tag, not knowledge/trivia/lateral thinking or something though. Still, could be the OP's mistake.

Comment: Actually, I thought of the places by myself, and they didn't come from a game. Also Billy doesn't die.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing

> He is home or on his way home.

And I think he was heading to

> The game store by walking past the farm to the cave, walking through the cave to get past the valley(and maybe also the forest and either got to the store before or after the park. But since the shop closed at 2:30 I'm just guessing he went back.

Comment: Good answer, but not correct. *make sure to analyze the text for small "clip hints"*